# MVEL expression : java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.Object

Tags: java, mvel

I am writing few MVEL expression `"$input.get('RESULT').array()[1]"` where `$input.get('RESULT')` return a `ByteBuffer`, so I am converting it into array using `array()` and then trying to get value of index 1. where array have 16 attribute.

But when Mvel executing this expression I am getting

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.Object
```

I am using below code

```
MVEL.executeExpression(statement, fieldContext.getContext(), fieldContext.getVariables());
```

I have written other expression as well which is working fine, I am getting this error for Byte one.

Any help here will be appreciated.

**Update :**
When I use `ByteBuffer` get method I got below error so I thought to give a try with `array`.

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class java.nio.HeapByteBuffer from class ASMAccessorImpl_2330495751530608772190
    at ASMAccessorImpl_2330495751530608772190.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at org.mvel2.optimizers.dynamic.DynamicGetAccessor.getValue(DynamicGetAccessor.java:79)
    at org.mvel2.ast.ASTNode.getReducedValueAccelerated(ASTNode.java:108)
    at org.mvel2.MVELRuntime.execute(MVELRuntime.java:86)
    at org.mvel2.compiler.CompiledExpression.getDirectValue(CompiledExpression.java:123)
    at org.mvel2.compiler.CompiledExpression.getValue(CompiledExpression.java:119)
    at org.mvel2.MVEL.executeExpression(MVEL.java:922)`
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to convert to `byte[]` with `array()`, it should be enough to

```
$input.get('RESULT').get(1)
```

as per [`ByteBuffer.get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#get(int)) method docs:

> public abstract byte get​(int index)
>
> Absolute get method. Reads the byte at the given index.

Comment: Initially I was using get method, but got `java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class java.nio.HeapByteBuffer` error so thought to try with array. please see my updates in question.

Comment: I was looking and found Mvel api build with  java 6, can this could cause a error here, do we have any changes in ByteBuffer api?

Comment: Nope, [Java 6 ByteBuffer#get(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#get(int)) is still there. Your `IllegalAccessError` might be caused by class loaders but it's impossible to tell without a running example.

Comment: I am using MVEL with spark, so compilation is happening on driver and execution of expression is happening on executor. this might causing this error.